# SQL or short cuts?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM nobel
WHERE winner = 'Theodore Roosevelt' or winner = 'Woodrow Wilson' or winner = 'Jed Bartlet' or winner = 'Jimmy Carter';
```

Is there a way to shorten this? Perhaps a way to use regex?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want the `in` operator:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM nobel n
WHERE n.winner IN ('Theodore Roosevelt', 'Woodrow Wilson', 'Jed Bartlet', 'Jimmy Carter');
```